# PHP, Bitmaps, and Redis

Tags: php, bitmap, redis

I found this blog post and would like to experiment with it more..  The issue is my environment is PHP and not Java.   I've looked for how I can translate the code examples I would like to use into PHP but it doesn't look like there is much documentation on PHP and Bitmaps.  Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

http://blog.getspool.com/2011/11/29/fast-easy-realtime-metrics-using-redis-bitmaps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do not really need to handle the bitmaps in the PHP code, provided you use a recent Redis version (2.6), and a compliant PHP client library.

See the following Redis commands:

- http://redis.io/commands/bitop
- http://redis.io/commands/bitcount

So you can count the bits directly in Redis rather than doing it in PHP.

Comment: thanks! and for anyone looking for a snippet of this check out http://avad.hu/t/content/realtime-metrics-using-bitmaps-redis-and-php

Comment: @ChrisWhittle, thanks for the link. The same page has changed URL to http://avadhutp.github.io/realtime-metrics-using-bitmaps,-redis,-and-php/